# Remainder of $37^{100}\equiv \pmod {29}$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm not allowed to use theorems, so I'm doing like this:

$$37^1 \equiv 8 (\mbox{mod} \ \ 29)$$
$$37^2 \equiv 6 (\mbox{mod} \ \ 29)$$
$$37^4 \equiv 7 (\mbox{mod} \ \ 29)$$
$$37^8 \equiv 20 (\mbox{mod} \ \ 29)$$
$$37^{16} \equiv 23 (\mbox{mod} \ \ 29)$$
$$37^{32} \equiv 7 (\mbox{mod} \ \ 29)$$
$$37^{64} \equiv 20 (\mbox{mod} \ \ 29)$$

However, if I double the exponent here, I'll get more than $100$. But if I multiply both sides by $37^{36}$ to get $37^{100}$ I'll not be able to compute $37^{36}$

> UPDATE: turns out my teacher won't let me multiply the congruences to
>   get another one. Is there a more elementar way of doing this by hand??

Comment: $37^{32}\times 37^{64} = 37^{64+32} = 37^{96}$ - can you continue from there?

Comment: See the [exponentiation by repeated squaring algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Comment: One way is to prove to your teacher that you can multiply congruences. Once something is proven you can use that something, that's how it works in math. Another way is ask him what you're allowed to do exactly. One of the allowed things will lead to the solution unless your teacher is pulling some jokes of course ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiply your 3rd , 6th and 7th lines. I think you will get your answer.

Comment: can I do it without multiplying the congruences?

Comment: I think without multiplying it is not possible...

Answer (score 5):

Note that: $$37^{100}=37^{64+32+4}$$

Answer (score 3):

$37^{32} \equiv 7\ (mod\ 29)$

Take this one to the degree of 3 and you're almost there (at degree 96). 
So you have:

$37^{96} \equiv 7^3\ (mod\ 29)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$

Now use the fact that:

$37^{4} \equiv 7\ (mod\ 29)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$

and multiply the congruences (1) and (2).

Now you're at degree 100 and you're done.
From here one can do it almost without writing: 
the end result is $37^{100} \equiv 7^4\ \equiv 49 . 49 \equiv 20 . 20 \equiv 400 \equiv 110 \equiv 52 \equiv 23\ (mod\ 29)$.

Comment: thanks. Could you give a look at my update?

Comment: One way is to prove to your teacher that you can multiply congruences. Once something is proven you can use that something, that's how it works in math. Another way is ask him what you're allowed to do exactly. One of the allowed things will lead to the solution unless your teacher is pulling some jokes of course ;)

Answer (score 2):

$37\equiv8\pmod{29}\equiv2^3$

$\implies37^{100}\equiv(2^3)^{100}\pmod{29}$

Now $2^5\equiv3\implies2^{15}=(2^5)^3\equiv3^3\equiv-2$

$\implies37|2(2^{14}+1)\implies2^{14}\equiv-1\pmod{29}$ as $(2,29)=1$

Now $300=14\cdot21+6$

$2^{300}=(2^{14})^{21}\cdot2^6\equiv(-1)^{21}\cdot2^6\equiv-64\equiv-6\equiv-6+29$

Answer (score 1):

I'm lazy. And I have trouble remembering all the fancy theorems, anyway. But since $37 > 29$, we may as well reduce that, first.

Now we're calculating $8^{100}$ (mod $29$), which at least is a "little" better.

Now using Fermat's Little Theorem is really the way to go, here (we could knock down that exponent in a hurry), but without it, we take a slightly longer path.

$8^{100} = (8^2)^{50} = 64^{50} = 6^{50}$ (mod $29$). Notice how I keep reducing the "base". This is to try to "keep it small" because exponentiating large integers is painful. Same thing again:

$6^{50} = (6^2)^{25} = 36^{25} = 7^{25}$ (mod $29$). Now since I don't really want to have to figure out what $7^5$ actually is, I'll cheat a little:

$7^{25} = (7^5)^5 = [(7^2)(7^2)7]^5 = [(49)(49)(7)]^5 =  [(20)(20)(7)]^5 = 2800^5$ (mod $29$).

Note that $28 = -1$ (mod $29$), so we can re-write this as:

$2800^5 = (-100)^5 = [(-1)(100)]^5 = -(100^5) = -(13^5) = (-13)^5 = 16^5$ (mod $29$)

(using the handy fact that $5$ is an odd number, so exponentiating $5$ times preserves signs).

Now I still don't feel like calculating $16^5$ (yes, I'm *that* lazy), so I do this:

$16^5 = (2^4)^5 = 2^{20}$ (mod $29$). Now I have a smaller "base" (even though my exponent went up a bit). The reason I did this was to write:

$2^{20} = (2^5)^4 = 32^4 = 3^4$ (mod $29$). Now I have a small base, AND a small exponent. THIS I can do in my head:

$3^4 = 81 = 58 + 23 = (2)(29) + 23 = 23$ (mod $29$). And done.